# python e**(-x) OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')

Tags: python

Is there a way in python to truncate the decimal part at 5 or 7 digits?

If not, how can i avoid a float like e**(-x) number to get too big in size?

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of x when it gives you that error?

Comment: the value is 0.xxxxxx (...) lots of them which blows the 32 bits available. I'm used to real languages like C where when it gets to the limit, automatically rounds up or down and that's what i want. I want to round to 6 or 7 decimal places. Any ideas?

Comment: "Real languages"... whereas python is the stuff of fairy tales. I often ride a Unicorn when I code in python.

Comment: @MarkByers.  Good question.  I tried very small and very large negative values and did not get and `OverflowError`.  I only got an overflow with a large positive number.

Comment: @Nitrate: x is 0.xxxxxx? That seems a bit of a recursive definition. What is xxxxx? Can you be more specific. Please use numbers instead of `x`s.

Comment: Aha!  `e` is a small floating point number, not `2.718281828459045`.  Try `0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001**-30`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: If x is negative then -x is positive. I'm not sure if Nitrate's "0.xxxxxx" notation excludes x from being a large negative number.

Comment: `real languages like C` are you saying that C's design of "undefined behavior, compiler can reformat your hard drive if it wants to" is the de facto reasonable way to implement overflows?

Answer (score 5):

Either catch the `OverflowError` or use the `decimal` module.  Python is not going to assume you were okay with the overflow.

```
>>> 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001**-30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
>>> d = decimal.Decimal(0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001)
>>> d**-30
Decimal('1.000000000000001040827834994E+1920')
```

Comment: +1 For also addressing that Python has chosen not to make assumptions for you.

Comment: If you use decimal.Decimal("1e-64") or "0.000[etc]1" you can avoid the error introduced by passing through the binary rep, at least if 10^(-64) was intended.

Comment: So with decimal i can make e = decimal.Decimal(math.e) and the use the 'e' in e**(-x) ?

Answer (score 2):

The "Result too large" doesn't refer to the number of characters in the decimal representation of the number, it means that the number that resulted from your exponential function is large enough to overflow whatever type python uses internally to store floating point values.

You need to either use a different type to handle your floating point calculations, or rework you code so that e**(-x) doesn't overflow or underflow.

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 7
math.exp(- Decimal(x))
```