# Python : Random variable gives OverflowError

Tags: python, random

I try to generate a random variable with a home made distribution with Python

I can plot the probability density function, but when I try to generate random numbers through the .rvs() method, I get an OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large') error.

Here is my code

```
class vdistrib(stats.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x):
        return x**2 * (0.000724/(2*math.pi))**(3/2) * np.exp(-0.000724* x**2)

rv_v = vdistrib()
x = rv_v.rvs(size=3)
print(x)
```

and this one is working

```
class vdistrib(stats.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x):
        return x**2 * (0.000724/(2*math.pi))**(3/2) * np.exp(-0.000724* x**2)

rv_v = vdistrib()
x = np.linspace(0.0, 100, 100)
y = rv_v.pdf(x)

figure1 = figure()
plot(x,y)
show()
```

Any help is welcome !

Thanks'

Pen

Comment: I have no idea of scipy and all this stuff, but maybe you are missing the "shape parameters for the distribution"? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.rvs.html#scipy.stats.rv_discrete.rvs

Comment: This should give you insight why do you get the error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643982/python-e-x-overflowerror-34-result-too-large

Comment: stats.rv_continuous has parameters to define the upper and lower limits of x.  Maybe you need to set those...  even though the mathematical function is well behaved, the computation may not be.

Comment: which version of `scipy` are you using @Penangol? Your first code seems to be working fine for me. I am using `0.14.0`